# passing a value when using .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

The addOnClickToPathContents() function is being used to add an onclick event to some dynamically created li tags such that when an li tag is clicked it calls the pathBuilder() function.  The pathBuilder() function requires one argument.  Is there a way to pass `fileList[f]` to pathBuilder as part of the .on() line of code?  If so, how?

```js
function addOnClickToPathContents(fileList)
{
 for(var f in fileList)
 {
  $('#' + fileList[f]).on('click', pathBuilder);
 }
}

function pathBuilder(file)
{
 console.log(file);
  //once this works, use file in logic within this function
}
```

Comment: That didn't work - nothing happened when the li was clicked.

Comment: That is closer; however, it seems to be firing pathBuilder() for every li in the list instead of just the one that is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use event delegation on the parent element. Lets say you have the `fileList` object with all the data for the file. The keys are the IDs of the list elements and in this case you don't even need a loop, just pick one value from the object upon the list id on click.
Keep it simple ;)

```js
(function($){
  
  var fileList = {
    file1: {data: {url: '/file1'}},
    file2: {data: {url: '/file2'}},
    file3: {data: {url: '/file3'}},
    file4: {data: {url: '/file4'}}
  }
  
  var fileBuilder = function(file){
    console.log(file);
  }
  
  $(function(){
    
    $('#fileList').on('click', '.file', function(){
      var file = fileList[this.id];
      fileBuilder(file);
    });
    
    
    
  });
})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="fileList">
  <li class="file" id="file1">File 1</li>
  <li class="file" id="file2">File 2</li>
  <li class="file" id="file3">File 3</li>
  <li class="file" id="file4">File 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yeah I think event delegation is the way to go here rather than adding all those handlers

Comment: This looks like a good approach.  However, I'm having difficulty getting it to work.  It may have to do with the data in my fileList which is JSON data coming from a PHP script.  The JSON.parse() returns this for data to be used in the jQuery function: `{"files": ["file1", "file2", "file3", "file4"]}`.  What modifications are needed to get this data to work with your recommended solution?

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways you can do this,

1) Bind the argument to the function:

```
function addOnClickToPathContents(fileList) {
  for(var f in fileList) {
    $('#' + fileList[f]).on('click', pathBuilder.bind(null, fileList[f]));
  }
}

function pathBuilder(file) {
  console.log(file);
}
```

2) Use an anonymous function to create a closure:

```
function addOnClickToPathContents(fileList) {
  for(var f in fileList) {
    $('#' + fileList[f]).on('click', function() {
      console.log(fileList[f]);
    });
  }
}
```

**Edit**: A more succinct approach that avoids jQuery id/class confusion.
Suppose you have a list:

```
<li class="file"></li>
<li class="file"></li>
<li class="file"></li>
...
```

You can iterate through these with jQuery:

```
$('.file').each(function(i, el) {
  $(el).click(pathBuilder.bind(null, fileList[i]));
});
```

Comment: Option 1 works fine - just had to add a closing paren to finish the .on().  After a LOT of time trying to figure this out, with no success, you aced it!  Fabulous!

Comment: Yea noticed that, and updated. That's what I get for typing it directly into the SO editor :)

Comment: @knot22 also keep in mind that `bind` takes a context as its first argument so if you ever need to use `this` in `pathBuilder`, you should pass something there instead of `null`. It's just common practice to pass `null` to indicate the purpose of the `bind` is not to change context.

Comment: OK.  There is one li tag where it didn't bind the event.  The eventless li tag has an id with a period in it: `id="finances.doc"`.  Is there a way to get the .bind() to work with ids that have periods in them?  Note that the string inside the double quotes of id is dynamically generated for the li tags.

Comment: @knot22 At this point, I would suggest a different design pattern. I can update my answer with a suggestion. The issue here is that jquery is reading `$('#finances.doc)` as something with `id="finances"` and `class="doc"`. You can avoid this by using plain javascript `document.getElementById` and `addEventListener` or using a jQuery each loop for you iteration or checking out the other answer to see if you like that idea.